# Expected property shorthand

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

I'm new to this and facing this error and not too sure what it means.

Error: Expected property shorthand at tree: tree - Triggered by eslint?

```
import {
  tree, tree1, tree2, tree3, tree4,
} from './Tree';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tree: tree,
      downloadingChart: false,
      config: {},
      // highlightPostNumbers: [1],
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ESLint wants you to use shorthand in the state object:

```
    this.state = {
      tree,
      downloadingChart: false,
      config: {},
      // highlightPostNumbers: [1],
    };
```

You don't have to declare the key and value if the variable you reference is the same name as the key you're defining. You can also deactivate this with ESLint's [object shorthand rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand).

Answer (score 3):

When the name of key is same as the value. You can write it once as shorthand.

```
this.state = {
  tree,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If your state property tree is same name as imported value tree, just try `this.state = {tree}`  without second one.